# How to extract all the activities names , intents and intent filters from Manifest file?

Tags: android, apk

i am working on a project where i want to extract all the activities , intents and intent filters. I have included the image of the [This is how i want the output to be after parsing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGbBA.jpg)[this image is how the activities and intents are there in the manifest file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmEGP.jpg)sample output as to how i want the output to be.

Comment: If u have the AndroidManifest file you can use SAX XML Parser or any other parsing libraries to parse the Manifest file and get what's required. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/xml-parsing-in-android-using-dom-parser/

Comment: i can extract only the activities , intents and intents filters as well?

Comment: depends on how you write the code. the library parses and gives you XML object.

Comment: How do we do it using python?